# Customizing the bar chart using Achart in andorid

Tags: java, android, charts, bar-chart, achartengine

[image]  I am drawing a bar chart using a chart i want to customize the chart.

1. give spave between first bar from start
2. Increase the width of each bar
3. incerese text size of numbers which are at top of the bars

Following is the code for my bar chart

```
 private void openChart()
 {

     int[] x = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6};



     // Creating an XYSeries for Income
     XYSeries wSeries = new XYSeries("Workout");
     // Creating an XYSeries for Expense

     for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
         wSeries.add(i,workout[i]);

     }

     // Creating a dataset to hold each series
     XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
     // Adding Income Series to the dataset
     dataset.addSeries(wSeries);
     // Adding Expense Series to dataset


     // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
     XYSeriesRenderer wRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
     wRenderer.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.header_blue)); //color of the graph set to cyan
     wRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
     wRenderer.setLineWidth(5);
     wRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
     wRenderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(20); //setting chart value distance 



     // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
     XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
     multiRenderer.setOrientation(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
     multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);

     /***
     * Customizing graphs
     */
    //setting text size of the title
     multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30);
     //setting text size of the axis title
     multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(30);
     //setting text size of the graph lable
     multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(30);
     //setting zoom buttons visiblity
     multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
     //setting pan enablity which uses graph to move on both axis
     multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
     //setting click false on graph
     multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
     //setting zoom to false on both axis
     multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
     //setting lines to display on y axis
     multiRenderer.setShowGridY(false);
     //setting lines to display on x axis
     multiRenderer.setShowGridX(false);
     //setting legend to fit the screen size
     multiRenderer.setFitLegend(true);
     //setting displaying line on grid
     multiRenderer.setShowGrid(false);
     //setting zoom to false
     multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
     //setting external zoom functions to false
     multiRenderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(false);
     //setting displaying lines on graph to be formatted(like using graphics)
     multiRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
     //setting to in scroll to false
     multiRenderer.setInScroll(false);
     //setting to set legend height of the graph
     multiRenderer.setLegendHeight(30);
     //setting x axis label align
     multiRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
     //setting y axis label to align
     multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
     //setting text style
     multiRenderer.setTextTypeface("sans_serif", Typeface.BOLD);
     //change y axis label color
     multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.BLACK);
     //change x axis label color
     multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
     //setting no of values to display in y axis
     multiRenderer.setYLabels(7);
     // setting y axis max value, Since i'm using static values inside the graph so i'm setting y max value to 4000.
     // if you use dynamic values then get the max y value and set here
     multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
     multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(49);

     //setting used to move the graph on xaxiz to .5 to the right
     multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    //setting max values to be display in x axis
     multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(7);
     //setting bar size or space between two bars
     multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(3);
     //Setting background color of the graph to transparent
     multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
     //Setting margin color of the graph to transparent
    multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_red));
     multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);

     //setting the margin size for the graph in the order top, left, bottom, right
     multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{20, 40, 20, 20});

     for(int i=0; i< x.length;i++){
     multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, week[i]);
     }

     // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
     // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
     // should be same
     multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(wRenderer);


     //this part is used to display graph on the xml
     LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.nut_sum_graphLayout);
     //remove any views before u paint the chart
     chartContainer.removeAllViews();
     //drawing bar chart
     mChart = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(HealthNutritionSummary.this, dataset, multiRenderer,Type.DEFAULT);
     //adding the view to the linearlayout
     chartContainer.addView(mChart);

    }![enter image description here][2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to give space on the left side a chart, I set X axis min to smaller size. For example, this should do the trick in your case.

```
multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
```

To increase width, you have two options.You can set bar spacing or bar width.

```
multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
```

or

```
multiRenderer.setBarWidth(20); // I think this is in pixels
```

And finally, for text size there is option for XYSeriesRenderer, in your case:

```
wRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);
```

Comment: How to increase Workout size which shown in question graph image for Bar Graph ?